# Issue with font (special characters) not showing correctly on webpage

Tags: html, css, wordpress, utf-8, font-face

So I have a small issue with typography on a website (made with Wordpress). It works fine on all pages and all browsers, except one page on safari that just won't show nicely. Normal characters have the right font but the special ones (éèà ..) use a different one.

I'm using the Suisse BP font, and it works well on other pages apart from this one, and the font is called the same way for each page.

Here are some screenshots of the issue:

on safari - mobile

[image: on safari - mobile]

on safari - computer

[image: on safari - computer]

Comment: I guess that it has something to do with [font substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_substitution). Maybe browser-specific if not declared correctly on a website (probably somewhere in CSS).

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref
follow the Character Entity Reference Chart at that link