# Special characters dont work properly with font - Only on Edge

Tags: html, css, fonts, web

im kinda new to this site (and to programming also), so sorry if i sound kinda dumb or something.
I started working on one site, for a company. I help with website, and learn at the same time.
My problem is, Edge doesnt show special characters (for example: č,ř,ě) - it shows them in another font!
I have no problem in Chrome.
!EDIT! So i figured out, font-face is not needed at all - its Google Fonts, so i only link them in head. Sorry, my bad.!
 Here is my @font-face:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'revicons';
  src: url('../fonts/revicons/revicons.eot?5510888');
  src: url('../fonts/revicons/revicons.eot?5510888#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/revicons/revicons.woff?5510888') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/revicons/revicons.ttf?5510888') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/revicons/revicons.svg?5510888#revicons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Im happy for any help, thank you
!EDIT! So i figured out, font-face is not needed at all - its Google Fonts, so i only link them in head. Sorry, my bad.!EDIT!

Comment: Please, open developer tools and make shure that fonts was loaded without errors.

Comment: Are your *fonts* folder and CSS-file placed in same directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using @font-face in Microsoft Edge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452288/using-font-face-in-microsoft-edge)

Comment: ok, so - fonts and css file are in same directory, and i have no duplicate @font-face, and i also added woff2 format in font-face. Can you please explain how to do first step? I open dev. tool with f12 and than what? Thanks for patience and help.

Comment: @Alexander please explain your first step -  
Please, open developer tools and make shure that fonts was loaded without errors - thank you

Comment: it's 2017, do not use this massive multi-format stack. The `eot` and `svg` font formats *no longer exist*, and if you use WOFF there is literally no point in also serving the *identical* ttf/otf equivalent system font. Step 1: simplify everything by using WOFF. And now you only have a single font that could be the problem, supported by [every modern browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105194/are-eot-ttf-and-svg-still-necessary-in-the-font-face-declaration/36110385#36110385)

Comment: @DanielKlein press **F12** and open *Console* tab. Then go to your web site.

Comment: so i removed eot and svg, no progress. In console, it says HTML1508
"Unmatched end tag.", HTML1504
"Unexpected end tag.", HTML1512
"Unmatched end tag." Is it problem? @alexander

Comment: so i removed all the unmatched end tags, still doesnt work :/

Comment: Are there no message so as *HTTP404: NOT FOUND* for your font file? It is usually includes actual absolute URL for the file. @Daniel Klein

Comment: No such errors, only with unmatched end tags (its my first website, so when i delete something, i sometimes forgot to delete </tr> for example) @Alexander

Comment: only HTML1300
"Navigation occurred", but on help side, i says "This is an informational message and not an error.", so i didnt even write it (i missed it too :D)

Comment: ok, @Daniel Klein . Is there any way to see your web-site online?

Comment: any thoughts? @Alexander

Comment: @Alexander this is exactly my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604318/issue-with-font-special-characters-not-showing-correctly-on-webpage . But there is no good answer for it :/

Comment: ok, so i just discovered something - it happens only in h1 and so on }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif; - in normal text it works @Alexander

Comment: @Daniel Klein, I does not find the *font* folder in web site resorces and does not look `@font-face` rule that is showed in the question. After your last comment I tried insert `<p style='font-family: "Yanone Kaffeesatz"; font-size: 150px;'>Kadeřnictví</p>` to text block, but **ř** character is still allocated.

Comment: guess i will try to change font and write results

Comment: @Alexander sorry my bad, fonts that are actually used are from google, im kinda confused now, trying another fonts and all

Comment: @Alexander sorry for confusion, fonts are from Google Fonts, i edited post also, i only link them in head and than later in css, no need for font-face, sry

Comment: @Daniel Klein, I already understood that the site uses Google fonts. But it does noes not mean anything. This should be worked in my opinion. I don't understand what is reason of the trouble. I voted up your question yesterday becose don't know how to help you.

Comment: @Alexander yeah i dont think there is any reason at all, i was on a lot of forums and didnt find anyhting at all, i guess i will somehow change font (find a good one) a go with it. However, its very interesting. One guestion, is there way to have different font on different browser? For example Arial font Edge and Times New Roman for Chrome (just example, not planning to use them)

Comment: @DanielKlein, I have seen, that the trouble is solved. How did you do it? Please, publish answer to own question.

Comment: @Alexander im pretty sure i just used another font, i just tried a lot of fonts and used only good ones